# Redirect user to some page in WordPress when the user is not logged In

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, redirect

I have an E-commerce Website in Wordpress. When the user clicks on the Buy button and if the user is not logged in it should redirect to some page and if the user is logged in then he can continue. Code added in functions.php but I am not able to add code for button click on buy. Any help much appreciated.

```
function loginCheck() {
 if(!is_user_logged_in()) {
 wp_redirect( 'www.xyz.com/get-a-pass', 302 );
 }
}
```

Comment: Are you using WooCommerce?

Comment: Yes @LukaPeharda

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using WooCommrece, then you can put the below code in your current theme's function.php file.

```
function wpse_131562_redirect() {
    if (
        ! is_user_logged_in()
        && (is_cart() || is_checkout())
    ) {
        // feel free to customize the following line to suit your needs
        wp_redirect(wp_login_url());
        exit;
    }
}
add_action('template_redirect', 'wpse_131562_redirect');
```

Note: all changes you done in function.php or other file are gone when you update theme. So prefer [Child Theme](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes).

Comment: On button, I have this code http://xyz.in/event/la-beach-picnic/?add-to-cart=1753.

Comment: function wpse_131562_redirect() {
    if ( ! is_user_logged_in() && (is_cart() || is_checkout()) ) {
        // feel free to customize the following line to suit your needs
        wp_redirect('http://xyz.in/get-a-pass/');
        exit;
    }
}
add_action('template_redirect', 'wpse_131562_redirect');  . This code I Have edited. But It is not Working . Please Help. @AddWeb Solution Pvt Ltd

Comment: Is my URL is correct or not. @AddWeb Solution Pvt Ltd

Comment: Not Working @AddWeb Solution Pvt Ltd

Comment: @Rahgav, It seems you missed http:// in your URL. Try to add http:// & check


 
// We are trying to redirect to another site, using a hard-coded URL.
wp_redirect( 'https://example.com/some/page' );

Comment: Can I also check whether the user has subscription plan or not? @AddWeb Solution Pvt Ltd

Answer (score 0):

you will need to disable ajax addto cart button on this options settings (Settings > product > Display):

try this code in functions.php

```
add_action('woocommerce_add_to_cart', 'custome_add_to_cart');
function custome_add_to_cart() {

 if(is_user_logged_in())
 {
    return true;
 }else
 {
    $url = 'https://www.google.com';
    wp_redirect($url);
    exit;

 }
}
```